# use operator overload definition from base class in subclasses in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, subclass

I'm currently digging deeper into C++. I have a problem with polymorphism / inheritance that I cannot figure out and did not quite find online answers that seemed (to me) to address my specific problem:

**I want to have a base class and several derived subclasses. I want to define common functions / operator overloads in the base class which the subclasses access, to avoid code duplication.**

Here's the example I am trying to figure out:

```
class ElectricalUnit {
protected:
    float value;

public:
    ElectricalUnit(float _value) : value(_value) {};

    float getValue() const {
        return this->value;
    }

    // this should be the (only) place where the add operation for all subclasses is defined
    // note: I intentionally want to avoid changing the objects' state by returning a new object
    ElectricalUnit operator+ (const ElectricalUnit& other) const {
        return ElectricalUnit(this->value + other.getValue());
    }
};


class Voltage : public ElectricalUnit {
public:
    Voltage(float _voltage) : ElectricalUnit(_voltage) {};

    float getVoltage() const {
        return ElectricalUnit::getValue();
    }

    Voltage operator+ (const Voltage& other) {  // not having this function did not work
        // 1st try:
        return ElectricalUnit::operator+(other); // error: says no conversion is available??

        // 2nd try:
        return (Voltage)ElectricalUnit::operator+(other); // error: also says no conversion is available.

        // 3rd try (read it online)
        ElectricalUnit::operator+(other);
        return *this;  // does give wrong values, because the return value of operator+ is not used
    }
};


class Current : public ElectricalUnit {
    private:
    float current;

    public:
    Current(float current) : current(current) {};

    float getCurrent() { return this->current; };

    /* use operator+ method from base class --> but how? */
};
```

Here, `Voltage` and `Current` are derived from the base class `ElectricalUnit`. Adding voltages or currents (or others like powers, energies, etc) is the same in every subclass. So in `ElectricalUnit` I define the operator overloading method and want the subclasses to use this method. The operation might get more complex when considering tolerances, etc. My aim was to have only one method where the logic is implemented.

Here's a sample program:

```
int main() {
    Voltage u1 = { 4 };
    Voltage u2 = { 6 };
    Voltage u3 = u1 + u2;
    Voltage u4 = u3 + u2;


    std::cout << "Voltage U1 = " << u1.getVoltage() << " V" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Voltage U2 = " << u2.getVoltage() << " V" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Voltage U3 = " << u3.getVoltage() << " V" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Voltage U4 = " << u4.getVoltage() << " V" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How do I accomplish this, or did I missunderstand something? I am a Python programmer, where this works without considering types at all ^^

I am glad about every help :) thank you.

Comment: The `operator+` overload that's implemented in the base class returns an `ElectricalUnit` object. That's it. Even if this `EletricalUnit` is a subclass of a `Voltage`, this `operator+` overload still returns an `ElectricalUnit`. Setting aside the issue of using the overload in the derived class, this is just how C++ works and there is no way to change that.

Comment: Inheritance is a wrong tool for this job. You may want to study a library that implements this functionality, such as [boost.units](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_units.html). It is about 1e6 times more complex that I can describe here unfortunately, and for lots of good reasons too.

Comment: *I am a Python programmer, where this works without considering types at all* -- And you've now seen that Python is not C++, and that using Python (or any other language) techniques in C++ just will not work.  C++ is one of the most complex languages out there, and you will get nowhere fast if you attempt to incorporate idioms and techniques from other language in C++.  The fact that C++ is value based, while Python and other languages are reference-based has bitten you here. 
 The proper way to do this is to forget that Python exists, learn C++ proper, and use C++ as C++.

Answer (score 1):

There's a conversion issue with the `Voltage::operator+` return value since polymorphism only works on pointers and references. The function returns a value and you're trying to return an `ElectricalUnit` where `Voltage` is expected.

What you need to do is explicitly create a new `Voltage` instance based on the `ElectricalUnit::operator+` return value like below.

```cpp
Voltage operator+(const Voltage& other)
{
    return Voltage(ElectricalUnit::operator+(other).getValue());
}
```